# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'work-groups'

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am having some trouble with my angular router, I keep getting this error and I know it is something very basic, but I don't have much experience with angular, thus I am asking for your help:

my html link:

```
<a href="" class="dash-nav-dropdown-item" routerLink="/work-groups" routerLinkActive="active">Work Groups</a>
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input'
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routes'
import { CreateWorkerComponent } from './component/create-worker/create-worker.component';
import { MaintainWorkGroupComponent } from './component/maintain-work-group/maintain-work-group.component';

import { Session } from './model/entity/Session';
import { ListWorkGroupComponent } from './component/list-work-group/list-work-group.component';
import { ItemWorkGroupComponent } from './component/item-work-group/item-work-group.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './component/dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CreateWorkerComponent,
    MaintainWorkGroupComponent,
    ListWorkGroupComponent,
    ItemWorkGroupComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    Session,
    AppComponent,
    ItemWorkGroupComponent,
    MaintainWorkGroupComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    ItemWorkGroupComponent,
    MaintainWorkGroupComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`app.routing.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'

import { DashboardComponent } from './component/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ListWorkGroupComponent } from './component/list-work-group/list-work-group.component';

const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: '/work-groups', component: ListWorkGroupComponent }
]
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
  })
  
  export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I have also tried to export my routes as a constant and use it in my `app.module.ts` but it did not work as well.

I really do not know what I am missing, please if you need more info just let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the preceding forward slash from the route:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'work-groups', component: ListWorkGroupComponent } <== SEE HERE
]
```